# Recognizing words ending with question marks and place span tags around them while typing

Tags: javascript, html, regex

---

### Goal: Recognizing words ending with question marks and place span tags around them while typing

---

> **INFO:** I have a container where the text inside is editable. Now while the user is writing something, I want the program to parse the text and place any word ending with a question mark inside a span tag. How can I achieve this?

Thank you in advance

**Html**

```
<div id='wrapper' contenteditable='true'></div>
```

**Javascript**

```
let wrapper = document.getElementById('wrapper');
let rgx = /([a-zA-Z]+)(\?)/g;

function update() {
    let hits, result;

  hits = wrapper.innerHTML.match(rgx);
    result = wrapper.innerHTML;

  for (let hit of hits) {
    result = result.replace(hit, '<span>' + hit + '</span>');
  }

  wrapper.innerHTML = result;
}

wrapper.addEventListener('input', function(e) {
    update();

  e.preventDefault();
})
```

**Style**

```
span {
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #8e44ad;
}
```

Comment: What you're searching for is [mark.js](https://markjs.io). Don't use `innerHTML` as it'll destroy events and trigger regeneration of the DOM over and over again.

Answer (score 1):

Try this regex `/\b(\w+)\b\?/g`

And replace with `"<span>\1</span>"`

Or `"<span>" + hit[1] + "</span>"`

[See on regex101](https://regex101.com/r/Ls40Yx/3)

Comment: This solution removes the interrogation point, which I'm not sure is desired. If you want to keep it, just use `\0` instead of `\1`, or `hit[0]` instead of `hit[1]`

Comment: Oh btw, the second `\b` isn't needed : if a `\w` is followed by a `\?`, there's an implicit `\b` between them. Nice answer anyway

Comment: Interesting, but it does that solve the fact that my cursor goes to the start everytime I start writing? Right now I cant truly continue typing new words, I keep on staying on that span so it cant continue working properly

Comment: What about saving cursor position, change text, then set it back? Preferably you should do that with selectionStart and selectionEnd to avoid losing selections too. I searched and found a several good answers on this on SO.

Comment: @NicolasMaltais you are right. I might have to update the cursor position every time though. Might not matter though. Ill try it out and show you

Comment: @NicolasMaltais Actually, with the selection range api right?, however, im not selecting anything so that wont work.

Comment: If you set selection start and end at the same position, it will only position the cursor.